# Deploy my REST API's on AWS when the API's aren't supposed to be public API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc

I have an application which is built using Spring MVC and the backend is REST API also built using spring MVC framework.

The request from the browser first hits the springMvc app which then calls my REST API for data. I do not have any needs to expose my API's publicly. So I am not thinking to use any API gateway.

For security, am thinking to host my REST app in a private subnet and host the springMVC app in public subnet in a VPC.

My question is what if some developers would like to test the API's directly , what provisions are available in AWS to manage this in development environment.

I am using AWS cognito for authentication and am just going to validate the token in the REST app for additional security. At netwrok level, I am planning to use Netwrok ACLs to restrict the REST app to be only called by my springMVC app. Basically one public subnet and one private subnet.

Please help if my understanding is correct in this regards and would it cause any design issues later on.

If at some stage later, I plan to expose my API's to lets say a mobile app, I might have to do some rework. Is it worth it to think about future now and design accorindgly considering it might not take much time if I am on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use API Gateway to create private APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html) that are only accessible by your VPC. You should consider using this option if possible. There are a lot of things that are difficult to manage when it comes to APIs such throttling, caching, and logging. Using API Gateway a lot of the scaffolding and instrumentation work for the API will already be done. You can  also [connect Cognito user pools to the API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html).

[This blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/) has a good overview and an example.